# In Unity Desktop, is there a way to hide *some* windows but not others in the window list?

Tags: unity, window

I have multiple windows that are always open, I know they're open, and I don't really care to know they exist. Specifically, I keep irc open in a window, and a live webcam in a window, scattered around different pieces of my desktop.

Is there any way to tell the window list not to show these windows? They're all marked to view on all workspaces if that helps....

Right now my window list, in the panel, shows

[ Menu Icon Icon Icon][ Chrome: IRC] [Chrome: webcam view] [Chrome: stackoverflow] [Chrome: related documentation] [Terminal] [Eclipse]

What I want

[ Menu  Icon Icon Icon] [Chrome: stackoverflow] [Chrome: related documentation] [Terminal] [Eclipse]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: *window list not to show these windows?*

Comment: Updated question to explain better

Comment: Not sure yet, you mean in the Launcher (on the left)? The panel (top) lists no windows, the launcher only a single icon per application. Could you add a link to a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Unity and have a "taskbar". I have a few apps that run at startup that launch full screen and when you minimize them they sit in the taskbar.. I used a program called gDevilspie which does have an option to skip_tasklist (Remove the window from the window list) not sure if this may work for what you want to do but I figured I would give you the information and let you give it a try.

Downfall with it is, if you want to view one of them you have to stop gDevilspie or it will just remove it again ... like the one thing I have done this with has a tray icon and if I try to show the window .. it minimizes and hides the taskbar entry again... I have to stop the program to view the window again :( This program is good if its something that needs to be running all the time but no interaction needs to be done with it ..and you just want to hide it from view as if it was running as a service in the background or something.

My other suggestion would be to set up multi-workspaces and just move those windows to one of the desktops not in view and change it so that they dont show on all workspaces .. then the ones "hidden" on a non visible workspace will not show on your main workspace ... not sure if it will change the windows list though... it does with xubuntu.